# volume must be a mapping not a string when binding files

Tags: docker, nginx

Currently trying to bind two files together, I've checked with other questions but can't find the answer. I even pasted this code into http://www.yamllint.com/ and it tells me this is valid YAML. I've tried placing `nginx_config/nginx.conf.template:/etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.templates` at the bottom but yamllint places is second from the bottom (not sure what difference this makes). What exactly is wrong here?

```
volumes:
  couchdb3_data:
    driver: local
  minio_data:
    driver: local
  nginx_config/nginx.conf.template: /etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.templates
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

Edit: This is the full file:

```
services:
  app-service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: budibase.docker.scarf.sh/budibase/apps
    container_name: bbapps
    environment:
      SELF_HOSTED: 1
      COUCH_DB_URL: http://${COUCH_DB_USER}:${COUCH_DB_PASSWORD}@couchdb-service:5984
      WORKER_URL: http://worker-service:4003
      MINIO_URL: http://minio-service:9000
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SECRET_KEY}
      INTERNAL_API_KEY: ${INTERNAL_API_KEY}
      BUDIBASE_ENVIRONMENT: ${BUDIBASE_ENVIRONMENT}
      PORT: 4002
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      LOG_LEVEL: info
      SENTRY_DSN: https://a34ae347621946bf8acded18e5b7d4b8@o420233.ingest.sentry.io/5338131
      ENABLE_ANALYTICS: "true"
      REDIS_URL: redis-service:6379
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
      BB_ADMIN_USER_EMAIL: ${BB_ADMIN_USER_EMAIL}
      BB_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD: ${BB_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD}
      QUERY_THREAD_TIMEOUT: 10000
    depends_on:
      - worker-service
      - redis-service

  worker-service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: budibase.docker.scarf.sh/budibase/worker
    container_name: bbworker
    environment:
      SELF_HOSTED: 1
      PORT: 4003
      CLUSTER_PORT: ${MAIN_PORT}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SECRET_KEY}
      MINIO_URL: http://minio-service:9000
      APPS_URL: http://app-service:4002
      COUCH_DB_USERNAME: ${COUCH_DB_USER}
      COUCH_DB_PASSWORD: ${COUCH_DB_PASSWORD}
      COUCH_DB_URL: http://${COUCH_DB_USER}:${COUCH_DB_PASSWORD}@couchdb-service:5984
      SENTRY_DSN: https://a34ae347621946bf8acded18e5b7d4b8@o420233.ingest.sentry.io/5338131
      INTERNAL_API_KEY: ${INTERNAL_API_KEY}
      REDIS_URL: redis-service:6379
      REDIS_PASSWORD: ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    depends_on:
      - redis-service
      - minio-service
      - couch-init

  minio-service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: minio/minio
    volumes:
      - minio_data:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: ${MINIO_ACCESS_KEY}
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: ${MINIO_SECRET_KEY}
      MINIO_BROWSER: "off"
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000/minio/health/live"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 3

  proxy-service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${MAIN_PORT}:10000"
    container_name: bbproxy
    image: budibase/proxy
    environment:
      - PROXY_RATE_LIMIT_WEBHOOKS_PER_SECOND=10
      - PROXY_RATE_LIMIT_API_PER_SECOND=20
    depends_on:
      - minio-service
      - worker-service
      - app-service
      - couchdb-service

  couchdb-service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: ibmcom/couchdb3
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=${COUCH_DB_PASSWORD}
      - COUCHDB_USER=${COUCH_DB_USER}
    volumes:
      - couchdb3_data:/opt/couchdb/data

  couch-init:
    image: curlimages/curl
    environment:
      PUT_CALL: "curl -u ${COUCH_DB_USER}:${COUCH_DB_PASSWORD} -X PUT couchdb-service:5984"
    depends_on:
      - couchdb-service
    command: ["sh","-c","sleep 10 && $${PUT_CALL}/_users && $${PUT_CALL}/_replicator; fg;"]

  redis-service:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

  watchtower-service:
    restart: always
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: --debug --http-api-update bbapps bbworker bbproxy
    environment:
      - WATCHTOWER_HTTP_API=true
      - WATCHTOWER_HTTP_API_TOKEN=budibase
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
    labels:
      - "com.centurylinklabs.watchtower.enable=false"
  volumes:
    - /nginx_config/nginx.conf.template: /etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.templates

volumes:
  couchdb3_data:
    driver: local
  minio_data:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

I tried putting the line under the services section but not it's telling me:  `service 'volumes' must be a mapping not an array`

Comment: The `volumes` section of your `docker-compose.yaml` can only contain references to docker volumes. To bind mount a file, you need to place that in the `volumes` section **of a service configuration**. Please update your question to show your complete `docker-compose.yaml` and we can probably help you out.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the reply, I just added the full file, along with the changes you suggested. Now I'm getting this error: `service 'volumes' must be a mapping not an array`

Comment: Underneath `watchtower-service`, `volumes:` needs to be indented one step more, and there needs to not be a space after the colon.

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do -- bind-mount a file into a container -- you need to specify that in the `volumes` section of a *specific service*. So, for example, if you wanted to mount the file `./nginx_config/nginx.conf.template` into a service named `nginx`, you would write something like:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: docker.io/nginx:mainline
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config/nginx.conf.template:/etc/nginx/templates/nginx.conf.templates
```

You're already using the correct syntax in other services in your `docker-compose.yaml` file (e.g., where you're bind-mounting the docker socket in your `watchtower-service` service). This is just the same thing, with a file instead of a socket.

Good reading on this topic includes the [compose syntax reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) as well as the [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) documentation.

Comment: Ah I see thank you, would it also be acceptable to place it under an existing service? Such as `proxy-service` which I already have? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Of course you can place it under an existing service. I was just demonstrating the syntax; you can add that to the volumes block of any service.

Comment: Okay perfect I was able to successfully run `docker-compose up -d`! I have one more question: when I make changes to my hosts file it should reflect in the container file right? Do I need to restart nginx on the container to see those changes? I'm not seeing them currently

Comment: When you say "your hosts file", are you referring to `/etc/hosts` on your host? Changes to that file would not be reflected in your container.

Comment: Sorry I mean on the machine that contains docker. The one with `./nginx_config/nginx.conf.template`

Comment: I'm still not clear *which* file you're asking about. If you are asking "will changes to `./nginx_config/nginx.conf.template` be reflected in the container?", the answer is "yes"...but only in the template file. The nginx container only processes the templates when the container starts up, so you would need to restart the container to actually update the running configuration.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean thank you.  And `docker-compose up -d` wouldnt accomplish that obviously?

Comment: Stupid question I need to run `docker restart [container]`

Comment: Probably `docker-compose restart <service>` will be more convenient. If that doesn't work, you may want to open a new question. I think we're beginning to abuse the comments :).